# add to favourites (bookmarking) something on iPhone sdk

Tags: html, sdk, iphone, bookmarks

i am working on an application that parses html data and then displays it in a table. now I want to some how add the add to favourites functionality to it. I am new iPhone SDK so if there are any tutorials that would be helpful.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. You can store the data in a SQLite DB (or use CoreData) or you can use NSUserDefaults to store data. If you are storing a lot of data it is better to use the DB. NSUserDefaults is best for storing user settings etc.

Here is the [NSUSerDefaults Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Here is an [introduction to CoreData](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html)